# Java Regex: Matching Multiple Occurrences

Tags: java, regex

I have a list of phone numbers and other text such as the following:

```
+1-703-535-1039  +1-703-728-8382 +1-703-638-1039  +1-703-535-1039
```

And I'm trying to match just the area code and first 3 digits of the number.

Currently I'm using the following Regex:

```
\d{3}-\d{3}
```

But it only returns the first match instead of all matches.

Pls see this link for reference:

https://regex101.com/r/oO1lI9/1

Comment: Did you actually try this with Java? In regex101, if you want all the matches use `g` modifier.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is one of those questions http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285733/should-give-me-a-regex-that-does-x-questions-be-closed/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regex101, use global `g` flag to get **all** matches

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/oO1lI9/2)

[image]

To get all matches in Java:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\d{3}-\d{3})");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("+1-703-535-1039  +1-703-728-8382 +1-703-638-1039  +1-703-535-1039");

// Find all matches
while (matcher.find()) {
    // Get the matching string
    String match = matcher.group();
}
```

[Reference](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Regular-Expressions/Findallmatches.htm)

Comment: The original answer targeted the question, not the edited answer. However, I realized I need the area code and the first 3 digits WITHOUT the dash (-) in between. I tried this:      `\d{3}(?=-)\d{3}` (positive look ahead) but I did not get any matches..

Comment: @KayMart, `(?=-)\d{3}` matches three digits when the first digit is also a dash, which can never be the case.  Lookaheads match without consuming output, but what you seem to want is for the output of the match not to include the dashes.  Your best bet is to strip the dashes from the output as a second step.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "global" flag in java regex.